# Why Django allow accents in email adresses?

Tags: django

I use custom `User`model, and I used [normalize_email()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager.normalize_email) method on email field.
Following the doc, it seems that this method lowercase the domain portion only.

However, when I'm creating a user, it allow email with accents like : "léa.loué@gmail.com".
I think normalize_email should remove these accents.

SHould I override the method? Or do you think it's better to use a special REGEX validator on email form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is part of RFC 6531 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6531).  Unicode characters in UTF-8 are allowed.

Comment: Thanks for this. Then, the problem comes from my SMTP server (Mandrill/Mailchimp) who can't send emails when there is an accent in address.